# Парсинг RSS на сайт PHP из Гос Закупок

Tags: php, curl, xmlparser, rss

Есть лента RSS из Гос закупок, есть желание её съесть и распарсить, однако иногда, когда она кушается, она выдает "Страница не найдена" вместо rss, причём она появляется как в браузере, так и в съеденом запросе, как это убрать, есть ли способ решить проблему?

[Ссылка на страницу,выдающую rss.](https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/eruz/search/results.html?morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&sortBy=BY_REGISTRY_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_50&showLotsInfoHidden=false&participantType_0=on&participantType_1=on&participantType_2=on&participantType_3=on&participantType_4=on&participantType_5=on&participantType_6=on&participantType_7=on&participantType=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7&registered=on&excluded=on&rejectReasonIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&address=%D0%B3.+%D0%A2%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

[Сама ссылка на rss](https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/eruz/search/rss.html?morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&sortBy=BY_REGISTRY_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_50&showLotsInfoHidden=false&participantType_0=on&participantType_1=on&participantType_2=on&participantType_3=on&participantType_4=on&participantType_5=on&participantType_6=on&participantType_7=on&participantType=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7&registered=on&excluded=on&rejectReasonIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&address=%D0%B3.+%D0%A2%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Вот так я беру с сайта данные:

```html
<?
function curl_get($url, array $get = NULL, array $options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url . (strpos($url, "?") === FALSE ? "?" : "") . http_build_query($get) ,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, //unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, //unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


    if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

?>

<?function get_xml(){
    $xml=curl_get('https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/eruz/search/rss.html?morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&sortBy=BY_REGISTRY_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_50&showLotsInfoHidden=false&participantType_0=on&participantType_1=on&participantType_2=on&participantType_3=on&participantType_4=on&participantType_5=on&participantType_6=on&participantType_7=on&participantType=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7&registered=on&excluded=on&rejectReasonIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&address=%D0%B3.+%D0%A2%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C', array(), array());
    return($xml);
}?>
```

Comment: Ну так повтори запрос при ошибке

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ваш айпи временно блочат во избежание перенагрузки сервера. Попробуйте в коде программы предусмотреть эту ошибку, и через некоторое время попробовать еще раз сделать запрос.

Comment: Я думаю ты прав, поставила функцию, которая каждые 10 секунд перезагружает, пока данные не получит, получается хорошо.

Comment: не забудьте поставить максимальное количество неудачных ошибок. В противном случае если сайт к которому вы обращаетесь будет недоступен то ваш скрипт будет постоянно висеть  и работать (время зависит от вашего конфига)